# JQuery position do not have information when showing an element after being hidden

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

I'm trying to get the position of an element when the ajax success callback is executed which inside a call to `html()` function has added the content to a bootstrap dialog.  It returns 0

Here's the modal:

```
<div id="ShipmentModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">@Resource.ShipmentDialogTitle...</h4>
            </div>
            <div id="ShipmentText" class="modal-body">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <a data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="SaveOrder($('#ShipmentForm').serialize())">@Resource.Save</a>
                <a class="btn btn-primary" onclick="GetShipmentPrices($('#ShipmentForm').serialize())">@Resource.Execute</a>
                <button id="DismissShipmentModal" type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">@Resource.Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Shipments/GetShipmentPrices',
    type: 'POST',
    data: Model,
    success: function (Result) {
        if (Result.Success) {
            $('#BusyIndicator').fadeOut(function () {
                            $('#DismissShipmentModal').click();
                            $('#PricesText').html(Result.View);
                            $('#PricesModal').modal('show');
                        });
        }
        else {
            $('#BusyIndicator').fadeOut(function () {
                if (Result.Exception != "") {
                    $('#DismissShipmentModal').click();
                    $('#ResultText').html(Result.Exception);
                    $('#ResultModal').modal('show');
                }
                else {
                    $('#ShipmentText').html(Result.View).promise().done(function () {
                        var Element = $(this).find(".field-validation-error:first").closest('.form-group');
                        $('.modal-body').animate({ scrollTop: Element.position().top - 150 }, 1300, function () {
                            var ControlName = $(".field-validation-error:first").data("valmsg-for");
                            var Control = $("input[name='" + ControlName + "']");
                            $(Control).focus();
                        });
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        $('#BusyIndicator').fadeOut(function () {
                        $('#DismissShipmentModal').click();
                        $('#ResultText').html(GetResponseText(jqXHR.responseText));
                        $('#ResultModal').modal('show');
                    });
    }
});
```

I expect to be able to get the position of the element

When the dialog appears the element is hidden then if the user clicks a certain property the element is rendered to the user and then a call to the controller go validate the form and return and I should be able to get the element position since the element was shown to the user and the position should be available with jquery position()

Comment: NOTE: The element I'm trying to get the position from is hidden at the creation of the form then it becomes visible BEFORE going to the controller so I'm wondering if it's because the element is hidden at first that the problem comes from there however I don't understand why I make it visible before trying to get the position of it in the success callback

Comment: I tried with a solution of position absolute and left to -999em in order to keep the element visible but with no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with a class I do remove and add accordinly and just making the section disabled rather then hidden however it's a workaround and the problem still exists.  Why an element that we make visible after being hidden doesn't have position information.

```
<style>
    .disableSection {
        pointer-events: none;
        background-color: lightgray;
        opacity: .3;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
    }
</style>
```